# When and how are React lifecycle methods called in the NextJS SSR process?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

This is a simple question that almost certainly is answered in the NextJS documentation somewhere, but after looking (as well as googling for some writeup about it) I can't find it.

As I understand it, NextJS works thusly:

- If you arrive at your app from an 'external' URL, that is, not through a `Link`, then the page is SSR'd, and NextJS sends a combo of HTML with JS (NextJS framework, React, etc) to the browser.  This HTML is produced through React, on the server.
- During the SSR `getInitialProps`is called *on the server* and (I assume) passes initial data down to the SSR process through `props`
- Then React lifecycle methods are called (`componentDidMount` /`useEffect`).  The application still has access to initial data through `props`.  As I understand it, these lifecycle methods are called on the client -- that's what my `console.log` tells me -- and thus you can be guaranteed access to things like `localStorage`.
- But does this imply that is there a *second* render on the client side *after* the original SSR, that is, the original HTML delivered is *replaced* by the SPA?
- Or does the original SSR content remain, but NextJS somehow calls the React lifecycle methods "directly"?

Part of the issue is that I have zero knowledge of how React works internally -- what relation painting the screen and lifecycle methods have with each other.

I'm trying to understand how NextJS works -- what exactly is the flow, and how NextJS' SSR and React work together, and what happens when and where.

Answer (score 6):

> But does this imply that is there a second render on the client-side after the original SSR, that is, the original HTML delivered is replaced by the SPA?

What you're describing is what's called the "rehydration" process. Next will return the server-side content and then rehydrate on the client-side through effects (e.g., `useEffect`) or data fetching client-side (e.g., [SWR](https://swr.now.sh/)).

I would recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC7j3DtOnYE) for a more detailed explanation from Tim, the lead maintainer of Next.js.